# Where is Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu() in Mono for Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to invalidate my current activity's option menu with Mono for Android. It seems that InvalidateOptionsMenu is a member function of Activity in Android, but in Mono for Android it is mysteriously missing.

How can I work around this? Note that I am currently not using the Fragmentmanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is available in Mono for Android as well, documentation can be found [here](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu).

It wasn't introduced until API level 11, so make sure you are targeting at least that level.

Comment: Yup, the API level was indeed the problem. Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately I need to target api level 9 and higher, so I guess I'll have to pass on the options menu.